# How to detect if code is run from IDE

Tags: delphi, ide

I have the following function that I use to check if my code is run from the IDE or not 
What is really frustrating is that from time to time the function returns False even if the code is run from IDE. And the fact that I can't find any common denominator for when it works OK and when it doesn't
Anyone got an idea as how to fix this function or a whole other method of doing this check.
(I use the function to make a menu with test functions available during development and hide them to end user)

```
function IDERunning: Bool;
begin
  Result := (FindWindow('TAppBuilder', nil) > 0) and
    (FindWindow('TPropertyInspector', 'Object Inspector') > 0);
end;
```

I use Delphi XE8

Comment: For the same reason I use a conditional define 'DEBUG' which is set when Build configuraion is 'Debug'. End users only get versions build with  'Release' configurations.

Comment: You should be using `<>` instead of `>`.  But in any case, `FindWindow()` only tells you if a top-level window with the specified class/title exists, but not whether the window is actually associated with the calling process.  What if the IDE is running, but your app is run outside of the IDE? Your code above would think the code was run in the IDE when it really isn't. Besides, `FindWindow()` only searches top-level window, and the `TPropertyInspector` window is not a top-level window if the Object Inspector is docked (it is actually several levels deep when docked).

Comment: @Tom Brunberg - that solution has slipped my mind. But it is the easiest one I can see now I have been made aware of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to test:

- Use [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx) to test if any user mode debugger is attached to your process.
- Test if [`DebugHook`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DebugHook) is non-zero to determine that the program is running under the Delphi IDE debugger.

Note that when `DebugHook` is non-zero, then `IsDebuggerPresent` will return true, but the reverse is not always the case. There are debuggers other than the IDE debugger.

Comment: googling around it seems that the best solution should be `if (DebugHook <> 0) or IsDebuggerPresent then`

Comment: @fant That's pointless whenever the former condition is true, the latter one is. IsDebuggerPresent is always True when DebugHook is non-negative.

Comment: I think I will start with testing the conditional define as suggested by Tom Brunberg and the move on to the DebugHook

Answer (score 5):

The [IsDebuggerPresent function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx) from the `Winapi.Windows` unit can be used.

Comment: I found that if Tools > Debugger Options > Integrated Debugging is turned off, then IsDebuggerPresent returns false.